# Not able to access user defined class from webservice

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services, serialization, deserialization

I am new to Web Technology. I have a WebService called `Sample`. It references a dll with name `Custom.dll`. My `WebMethod` is returning a class from `Custom.dll` which is marked as Serialization.

// My custom class

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("wsdl", "2.0.50727.3038")]
[SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://somthing-something.mydomain.com/")]
public class CustomClass
{
    public string id;
    public string key;
}
```

// My Web Service method

```
[WebMethod]
public CustomClass MyWsMethod()
{
    return new CustomClass{id="id", key="Key"};
}
```

Also to mention, my webservice is a WCF Service and has a `asmx` file in it.

I am consuming this webservice in my application and service referenced my webservice as `localhostWS`. My Application also references `Custom.dll`. When I am calling my webservice method then I am not able to get back the `Custom.CustomClass` object. I am returning `localhostWS.CustomClass` and also I am not able cast it to `Custom.CustomClass`.

`CustomClass custom = localhostWS.MyWsMethod();`

Here `custom` object is of type `localhostWS.CustomClass` but I was expecting `Custom.CustomClass`.

Can any body suggest me whats happening here. Please let know if I need to provide any further information. I have tried enough to be clear in my question.

**Edit**

I must also mention this, it will great to achieve this without changing any Client side code. Due to reasons it will not be possible to change that. However any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: WCF and ASMX are **not** the same thing - I'm not even sure you can have both in the same service, though I could be mistaken on that.  In either case, `localhostWS.customClass` and `Custom.CustomClass` will not be seen as the same thing by .NET even if the underlying code is identical, because they will be viewed as separate assemblies.

Comment: I am able to add asmx file in WCF service. And yes both are treated as different objects and this is what my problem is.